# Binary Tree delete Node() how to delete the roots until no root any more exist

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree

> Hello I just need help to delete a root. How can I do this? I can delete Nodes if it is not a root but if I try to delete a root I get problems. I have here a cutout of my code.

```
else if (curr->getLeft() && curr->getRight()) {
    
    /*HEEEEERRREEEEE*/
    if (root->getNodeOrderID() == NodeOrderID) {
        TreeNode* tmin = min(root->getRight());
        // parent_n = parent of minimum
        TreeNode* parent_n = parent_node(root,tmin->getNodeOrderID());
        TreeNode* leftTree = root->getLeft();
        
        
        parent_n->setLeft(tmin->getRight());
        tmin->setLeft(curr->getLeft());
        tmin->setRight(curr->getRight());
        root = tmin;
        delete curr;
        
          return true;
    }
```

Comment: "Problems" is not good enough description of said "problems". Please show a [mcve].

Comment: What "problem"/issue are you facing?

Comment: Are `curr` and `root` the same reference? If not, what are they?

Comment: In your code(or part that is currently visible), you try to access parent of root(it is assumption based on your names). And after that you try to access some child of that root's parent. There is a big chance that parent of root is `nullptr`, so you cannot set any new child for that node. So I would recommend you to try and remove root without accessing root's parent

Comment: If you "delete" the root of a tree, what is left is two trees (a forest).

Comment: @dilsoziya Welcome to StackOverflow, the description of the question is ambious. It would be easier for us to understand your concern if you would clarify it with more details.  You can also visit [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)